# Websphere8.5 j2ee log out from single sign on

Tags: jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, logout, websphere-8

In a development environment I want to give testers the ability to logout of what will eventually be a single sign on environment to log in as a different user with different permissions.

My websphere server uses a local federated repository using LTPA.

When a user tries to access a restricted resource they're given a modal dialog login prompt. User accounts and group permissions are working exactly as expected. To this point, everything is so far so good.

In trying to log the user out I've tried HttpSession.invalidate(), HttpServletRequest.logout(), using the ibm_security_logout action, WSSecurityHelper.revokeSSOCookies(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse), expiring all the request cookies from both the server and client side.

While the session expires, I do not get a new login prompt. Something is remembering the user.

Documentation implies ibm_security_logout would revoke the LTPA token.

WSSecurityHelper.revokeSSOCookies is deprecated and I can find no information on what has replaced it. The documentation I've found suggests it was current as of WAS 6, but I can see that it no longer works.

Can I make the browser and server forget the user without forcing my testers to close their browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume that by `modal dialog login prompt` you meant popup from browser displayed during HTTP basic authentication. Unfortunately in that case, browser stores user credentials and re-sends them with every request, that's why you are not getting new login prompt.

To be able to logout, your application must use Form based authentication - you need to create login page and  modify web.xml of your application like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Your login page should contain the following form (simplification):

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="j_username" size="20"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="j_password" size="20"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

To logout user in that case you have 2 options:

### Form logout

In this case you have to create logout form, which should be posted to `ibm_security_logout` with optional redirection page parameter. That would remove session and LTPA cookie. See [this page](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-base-dist&topic=tsecpofolo) for details (look for Form logout).

```
<form method=POST action="ibm_security_logout" name="logout">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
    <input type="hidden" name="logoutExitPage" value="/login.jsp">
</form>
```

### Custom logout

In this case you create your own servlet, which will handle logout, and instead of using `revokeSSOCookies` just call `request.logout()` method, which is available in Servlet 3.0 API. Details are described in the [Servlet security methods](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-base-dist&topic=rsec_secgetru), but in general it:

- Clears the LTPA cookies if SSO is enabled
- Invalidates the HTTP session
- Removes the user from the authentication cache
- Removes the user subject from the thread
- Clears the caller and invocation subjects
- Sets the authentication type to null

One final comment - if you enable single sign on (e.g. using SPNEGO), your users will be automatically logged in, and by default they will not be able to logout and log in as different users. You would need to do custom configuration, but that's subject for different question ;-)